# Calling Function from another function Powershell

Tags: powershell

```
function main {
    $options = @('option1', 'option2', 'option3')
    CLS; $n = 1
    $options | foreach { "[{0}] {1}" -f $n, $_; $n++ }
    choice /c 123 /m "Choose:"
    "opt$lastexitcode"
    pause; main
}

function opt1 { "this is option one" }
function opt2 { "this is option two" }
function opt3 { "this is option three" }

main
```

If possible directly call other function with typing the name function without **if** or **switch** statement?

Comment: Yes - have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-switch?view=powershell-7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps use here the
[Invoke-Expression command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.4).

The article contains this example :

```
$Command = "Get-Process"
Invoke-Expression $Command
```

Keep in mind the warnings in the following article (which might not
pertain to your case):
[Invoke-Expression considered harmful](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).